# Android device manager IO error occurred while trying to rewrite a file

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-emulator

With Visual studio 2019 I created my first Xamarin Forms 5 project and tried to run it, and this is what happened. I tried copying the Android folder from drive "D" to "c:\ProgramFiles(x86)\Android" but that didnt help it either.
I have checked the path mentioned in this error and the "avd" folder there seems to be empty.

[image: error image]

Also when I press ok on this error the emulator image behind keeps saying that its updating, and it keeps going on forever apparently.

[image: updating]

Comment: firstly, check whether you have installed android by **Tool-Android-Android SDK Manager ** , then go to **Tool-Options-Xamarin-Android Settings** to check Android SDK location is default location **C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk.**

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT did all that and changed the sdk location to point to default location u mentioned and Android sdk does exist there bcz I copied it there, but still getting same error.

Comment: Can you try to delete this emulator ,recreate new emulator?